# Removed pod also removed the associated Framework

Tags: ios, xcode4, cocoapods

I had a podfile that looked like this:

```
platform :ios, '6.0'
xcodeproj 'NetApp.xcodeproj'

pod 'AFNetworking'
pod 'TTTAttributedLabel'
pod  '[x]'
```

Decided to remove `pod '[x]'` from my podfile, I then ran `pod install` and `pod update`. But  now I get the following warnings:

```
SystemConfiguration framework not found in project, or not included in precompiled header.  Network reachability functionality will not be available.
MobileCoreServices framework not found in project, or not included in precompiled header. Automatic MIME type detection when uploading files in multipart requests will not be available.
```

I have tried to add the frameworks manually both in Pods and my `Xcode-projplace`. But it dosn't seem to work, and some functionality is missing.

How can I resolve this? Is it possible to reinstall all pods some way?

**Update**

Seems like it wasn't the removal of the Pod that caused it. Did a `git revert`. But when I ran  `pod update` (updated `AFNetworking`) the warnings came back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just import the header files in **PROJECTNAME-Prefix.pch**

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
  ...
  #import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>
  #import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>
#endif
```